# Running Test with Jest, Firebase & React-Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to successfully run the boiler place App-test.js test that comes with the react-native installation. I have seen this test work "out of the box" with other projects, however, mine fails due to our integration with Firebase SDK. The long-term goal is to build out a test suite that mocks the calls to our firebase SDK (want to explore the following solutions: https://medium.com/stories-from-upstatement/jest-mocks-roasting-on-an-open-firestore-36fa55b76953, [How do you mock Firebase Firestore methods using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043886/how-do-you-mock-firebase-firestore-methods-using-jest) ), but I am stuck at the opening gates.

Here was the initial error I was receiving when trying to run the following command:

`npm test __tests__/App-test.js`

Error:

```
import { getFirebaseRoot } from './internal/registry/namespace';
export default () => ({
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import React from 'react';
    > 2 | import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
        | ^
      3 | import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
      4 | import '@react-native-firebase/auth';
      5 | import '@react-native-firebase/database';
```

It appears that our App.js file is the culprit.

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
import '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import '@react-native-firebase/database';
import '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';
import '@react-native-firebase/functions';
import '@react-native-firebase/storage';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './app/store';
import Navigator from './app/routes';
import { loginUser } from './app/domain/Common/auth/actions';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
  }

  // gets the current screen from navigation state
  getActiveRouteName = (navigationState) => {
    let routeName = null;

    if (!navigationState) {
      return null;
    }
    const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
    // dive into nested navigators
    if (route.routes) {
      return getActiveRouteName(route);
    }

    routeName = route.routeName;

    // for venues, append specific venue name
    if (route.params && route.params.venueName) {
      routeName += ` - ${route.params.venueName}`;
    }

    return routeName;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Navigator
          onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
            // track user screen changes in  Analytics
            const currentScreen = this.getActiveRouteName(currentState);
            const prevScreen = this.getActiveRouteName(prevState);

            if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
              analytics().setCurrentScreen(currentScreen);
            }
          }} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

After researching this issue, the most promising lead to resolve the problem appears to be the following, https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3035.

But I am now stuck with a new error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/kyjelly/micturnTwo/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/warnOnce.js:15
    const warnedKeys: {[string]: boolean} = {};
          ^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:14:18)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.101s
```

Here is the jest portion of my pacakge.json

```
 "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@react-native-firebase/app)"
    ]
  }
```

And here is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics': '<rootDir>/__tests__/__mocks__/firebase/crashlytics.js',
  }
};
```

Can anyone point my in the right direction? As I understand it, Jest has issues compiling certain files that are not native Javascript. But every solution I try leads to another rabbit hole of configuration attempts.

Answer (score 6):

I have a fix that have worked to me and it is not related to ignoring libraries but configuring the Jest to mock the functions that I'm going to use. I've followed [this comment](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3035#issuecomment-628733145) on the link you pasted.

Finally my code looks like:

```
export const setupModulesMock = (() => {
    jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/crashlytics', () => {
        return () => ({
            log: jest.fn(),
            recordError: jest.fn(),
            // Any function you want to use or mock
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Adding this to my jest.setup.js worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, the package should provide the jest setup. However, since it's not available, you'd need to create the mock implementations for each module of the Firebase package.

I have placed two files - `jest.config.js` and `jest.setup.js` and the latter is referenced in the former as a value of `setupFiles` property of the config.

Apart from other mock implementations, for Firebase, these are my setup. You could modify them based on your use case.

```
const mockedFirebaseCrashlyticsLog = jest.fn()
const mockedFirebaseCrashlyticsRecordError = jest.fn()
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/crashlytics', () => {
  return () => ({
    log: mockedFirebaseCrashlyticsLog,
    recordError: mockedFirebaseCrashlyticsRecordError
  })
})

const mockedFirebaseAuthSignInWithCustomToken = jest.fn()
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/auth', () => () => {
  return {
    signInWithCustomToken: mockedFirebaseAuthSignInWithCustomToken
  }
})

const mockedFirestoreCollection = jest.fn()
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/firestore', () => () => {
  return {
    collection: mockedFirestoreCollection
  }
})

const mockedFirebaseAnalyticsLogEvent = jest.fn()
const mockedFirebaseAnalyticsLogLogin = jest.fn()
const mockedFirebaseAnalyticsSetUserId = jest.fn()
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/analytics', () => () => {
  return {
    logEvent: mockedFirebaseAnalyticsLogEvent,
    logLogin: mockedFirebaseAnalyticsLogLogin,
    setUserId: mockedFirebaseAnalyticsSetUserId
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**I solved this by creating mock of *`@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links`* in this way**

```
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links', () => {
  return () => ({
    onLink: jest.fn(),
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `jest.setup.js` file, or a `___mocks___` folder, you probably want to add this code to one of those:

```js
jest.mock("@react-native-firebase/analytics", () => ({
  analytics: jest.fn(() => ({
    logEvent: jest.fn(),
    setUserProperties: jest.fn(),
    setUserId: jest.fn(),
    setCurrentScreen: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));
```